# OpenGL vs. wxMathPlot for real time plotting in wxWidgets?

Tags: real-time, wxwidgets

I am new to using wxWidgets,and am looking to do a continuous real time plot. I have done some research into real time (continuous) plotting tools available for wxWidgets.
 I am most interested in using **mxMathPlot** for the plotting with support of **mpFXYVector** for feeding in points.
(I know there's Numerix Library as well, but it seems like there wasn't much documentation on it)

However, I would like to do about **100 updates a second**? or 100 new points coming in a second.

Is this something that is feasible using mxMathPlot with mpFXYVector, or would this approach be too slow?

Or should OpenGL be considered?

Comment: Your monitor better be doing at least 100Hz too!

Answer (score 2):

Displaying a real time graph of data updated at 100 Hz update using wxMathPlot is feasible.

The following is a screenshot of an app using three wxMathplot instances, all showing data that is being updated at 128Hz

[image]

If you want the sort of real time graph where the old data vanish on the left as the new data appear on the right, but the amount of data shown is constant at, say, the last 10 seconds, then mpFXYVector is awkward to use.  For a discussion of how to deal with this, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589894/16582)

However, for a first pass, this framework should get you started

```
... in Myframe constructor

vector <double> xs, ys;
mpFXYVector * data_layer
mpWindow * graph;

// initialize

...

 // Set up 100 Hz timer

...

MyFrame::OnTimer( ... )
{

// add new data point(s)

 ...

// copy data into layer

data_layer.SetData(xs,ys);

// redraw

graph->Fit();

/*  Note that at this point we have requested a redraw
 But it hasn't taken place yet
 We need to return so that the windows system can update the screen etc
 We will back in 1/100 sec to do it all again.
 */

}
```

So, now the question is, how fast can we make this scheme go?  I have experimented with a timer event handler that does nothing more than keep track of how many times it is called.

```
void MyFrame::OnTimer2(wxTimerEvent& )
{
    static int ticks = 0;
    ticks++;

    static clock_t start;
    if( ticks == 1 ) {
        start = clock();
    }
    if( ticks == 1000 ) {
        double duration = (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        wxMessageBox(wxString::Format("1000 ticks in %f secs\n",duration));
        myTimer->Stop();
        return;
    }

}
```

The fastest I can make this go, on a powerful desktop, is 66 Hz.

Does this matter?

IMHO, it does not.  There is no way a human eye can appreciate a graph being updated at 100Hz.  The important thing is that the graph shows data acquired at 100Hz, without any losses or lags, but the graph display does not need to be updated so frequently.

So, in the app that produced the screenshot at the top of this answer and other similar apps I have developed, the graph is being updated at 10Hz, which the wxWidgets framework has no trouble maintaining, and the data acquisition is occurring at a much higher frequency in another thread or process.  Ten times per second, the graph display code copies the data that has been acquired in the meantime and updates the display.

Comment: Great! I actually saw some of your posts, and I wanted to message you to ask about this, so I'm glad you replied. You used MPFXYVector to help with feeding data in, right?

Comment: okay, great. Thanks so much! i'll start digging into it. Just wanted to make sure I was making the right decision before doing that.

Comment: hey ravenspoint, just a quick follow up to make sure im on the right path. I have set up a method that will add points one at a time to the mpFXYvector class. I'm trying to test it by feeding in points. What I have done so far is just implement a while loop in OnInit ( I also tried to override MainLoop) which increments x,y points and adds them to the mpFXYVector and then calls Fit() on the plot , however, when I launch, the application just freezes. 
I'm not sure if there's a better way to test? Or because I'm unfamiliar with wxWidgets, I am just doing this completely wrong.

Comment: I apologize, I think I must have explained it wrong. I did create a wxFrame, and within that I placed a wxPanel within which is a plot. I followed one of the samples in mathplot. I tried to graph a simple sine function, and it worked perfectly. However, it was a static graph. I'm having trouble figuring out where to feed in continuous points? Does this make more sense? I'm sorry to have mis-said what I meant.

Comment: OK, sounds good.  Added basic code framework to answer, showing a first pass solution.

Comment: great, thanks so much! I'm going to play around with it more and hopefully get it to work.